# How to sync iCloud Keychains between ios7 and OSX10.9

Tags: macos, synchronization, icloud, keychain, ios7

I am trying to write a program which shares keychain items between iOS7 & OSX 10.9. The 2 devices are a ipad3 & a Mac Pro sharing the same Apple ID.
    I specified the "kSecAttrSynchronizable" key with kCFBooleanTrue before calling the "SecItemAdd" API. 
    Actually, items saved by iOS was visible in Mac Keychain Access utility.However, they could not be read because its "access group" is related to the TEAM ID of the app producing them. If I save items on OSX 10.9, their access group was "appleaccount", which could be read by iOS neither.
   Also, I tried the "kSecAttrAccessGroup" attr, but in vain.
   So, anything I missed? I'll appreciate that if any hints are proposed.

Comment: iOS7 is still under NDA. Ask this question in Apple forum please.

Comment: Sorry. I think I don't quite get you. Did you mean that this feature should not be used yet?

Comment: No, you can start developing app for iOS7 now, but all the iOS 7 questions should be asked in https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios at the moment.